# How to use a Vue component like Infobox in Bing Maps

Tags: vue.js, bing-maps

I want to use my own Vue component like Infobox in Bing Maps.
I'm not sure that it possible, do you think that is ?

```js
// my parent component
components : {
     Infobox
}
mounted(){

     //...code loading Bing Maps

     this.infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox({latitude: 0, longitude: 0}, {
          visible: false,
          autoAlignment: true,
          htmlContent: Infobox //inject here my vue component
     });

     this.infobox.setMap(this.map);
}
```

[Bing Maps | Dev Center - Add custom infobox](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/addcustominfobox)

Comment: My question isn't understandable ?

Comment: For information, I don't wish to use any package like `vue-bing-maps` or other.

Comment: are you using a CDN to load Bing maps?

Comment: I get it like indicated in official documentation of Bing Maps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/creating-and-hosting-map-controls/creating-a-basic-map-control

Comment: you could register them as webcomponent, and then just use their tag ?

Comment: just to add a link ^^ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper

Comment: @Estradiaz, I tried this solution, but isn't possible because Bing Maps API doesn't interpret customElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is create another Vue app then mount it to the element which will create by `htmlContent` string.

```js
import Infobox from '...'

...
  mounted () {
    this.infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox({ latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }, {
      htmlContent: '<div id="infobox"></div>'
    })

    this.infobox.setMap(this.map)

    setTimeout(() => {
      let component = new(Vue.extend(Infobox))()
      component.$mount(document.getElementById('infobox'))
    })
  }
...
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pxfmzvt5/)

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zskfn3h5/)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, but if you want to use props of type String, they aren't reactive.

```js
propsData: {
    title: this.infobox[0]._options.title, //not reactive
    close: $this.closeInfobox, //works
    itineraryTransit: $this.itineraryTransit, //works
    itineraryCar: $this.itineraryCar, //works        
}
```